# Custom functions in django admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to costomise the display in the admin interface. I need one of the fields to display the name and date submitted for photo sharing site I'm creating, but I keep getting the following error:

```
global name 'datetimeConvertToHumanReadable' is not defined
```

Here's the full traceback: http://dpaste.com/822073/

My code

Model:

```
class Design(models.Model):
    designer_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='design_photos')

    def image_thumb(self):
        return '<img src="/media/%s" width="100" height="100" />' % (self.photo)
    image_thumb.allow_tags = True

    def datetimeConvertToHumanReadable(dt):

        # convert passed datetime to timestamp
        dt_stamp = dt.strftime("%s")

        # convert current datetime to timestamp
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_stamp = now.strftime("%s")

        # find difference between the two
        delta = int(now_stamp) - int(dt_stamp)

        # convert to (seconds ago, minutes ago, hours ago, etc...)
        if (delta < 60):
            return str(delta) + " seconds ago"
        elif (delta < 3600):
            return str(delta/60) + " minutes ago"
        elif (delta < 86400):
            return str(delta/3600) + " hours ago"
        elif (delta < 31536000):
            return str(delta/86400) + " days ago"
        else:
            return str(delta/31536000) + " years ago"

    def name_and_submitted(self):
        date_submitted = datetimeConvertToHumanReadable(date_submitted) 
        return '<div>%s<br />submitted %s ago</div>' % (self.designer_id, self.date_submitted)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Admin.py:

```
class DesignAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('image_thumb', 'title', 'description', 'name_and_submitted')
```

The image_thumb method works fine to display a thumbnail in the field, but the name_and_submitted method throws up the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `self` argument. That should solve the problem

```
def datetimeConvertToHumanReadable(self):
    dt = self.date_submitted
    # rest of your code goes here
```

The problem is that, when you are not passing the `self` argument, the function is not attached to the class and not callable through a model object. list_admin_display actually access the model instance and calls the function. In your case, it would be something like `design_object.datetimeConvertToHumanReadable` where design_object is each model instance displayed in the admin page. The argument `dt` is not passed as an argument, so you need to extract it within your function.

Hope this helps